# Regex. How do I check that terms between ` are written correctly (extra/missing spaces)

Tags: .net, regex

I'm translating a text with lots of text like this: `text`

I need a regex to filter strings that have mistakes like:

```
this is a`line`
```

and

```
this is `another`line
```

Basically, missing spaces before of after the ` character.

Periods, commas, etc. are OK.

The software I'm using is MemoQ, which uses .NET. Thanks.

Comment: What kinds of mistakes do you need to filter out?

Comment: I just updated my post to show the mistakes

Comment: @caliaa what can be inside the tick characters? Just letters, digits or? Also, what's accepted without space? Any sort of punctuation? "etc." is inaccurate, you need to be as specific as possible when asking questions here.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
[^\\s]`.*`[^\\s]|[\\s]`.*`[^\\s]|[^\\s]`.*`[\\s]
```

Which is matching for "anything surrounded by backticks" that doesn't have whitespace either side.

Depending on exactly what is in your 'lines' you probably want to narrow down the character class for the match (`.*` is very broad and probably not going to work in practise).